# Switch process from command line on a mac

Tags: python, macos, ipc

I have two python scripts `A and B` to record(and process) video from `2` cameras. When I start these scripts, a new python process starts to show the live feed. Now while recording, I send results from both `A and B` to script `C`. Script C decides which video feed should be shown(A or B).

How can I achieve this? Basically, all I want to do is to control the visibility of the Python processes with a command.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you need to interact with the scripts once they start running?

Comment: @ConfusedByCode With A and B - No. I just have to bring their corresponding python process back and forth.

Comment: Can you just run A and B in the background and keep C in foreground?

Comment: C is not doing anything, when I run A and B, they start a python process to display the live video feed. So the job of C would be to bring in front the right python process(spawned either from A or B)